# Global custom class on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, global, persist

I'm writing a simple chat web service with C# ASP.Net, which I am new to.

Server maintains a `List<ConnectedUser>`, where the `ConnectedUser` object is a class holding ID, username, and a list of waiting messages.

I want all connected clients to be able to access the list on the server.

I tried Application state, but I found it will not hold custom classes, even when I let it be serializable. I tried a static class holding the global variables. Neither persist changes between calls to the service.

How should I be doing this? Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't that be very runtime intensive, making SQL calls? Is it the most efficient way, or is there a best DBMS for this?

Comment: Not all databases are disk-backed. Not all databases use SQL. I suggest you use an in-memory table if you need fast performance.

Answer (score 1):

For storing custom class in Application State you don't need to Serialize/Deserialize and normally they can be accessible.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y8hhek39.aspx

Here is some threads talking about this:

- [Storing classes in Application State (ASP.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857391/storing-classes-in-application-state-asp-net)
- [Web Application and In-Memory State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175399/web-application-and-in-memory-state)

Comment: Will only work with a single worker process, on a single machine, so long as there are no worker process crashes.  So not suitable for production use, etc

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options (we use both):

1) Store the values to be accessible in a static class that is initialized in global.asax or on the first user request.

2) Store the values in [HttpRunTime.Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.cache.aspx), especially if it needs to be refreshed periodically (you can refresh in the timeout event).